# What is the Fourier transformation of $y=exp⁡(-λ|x|)$

Tags: fourier-transform

What is the Fourier transformation $y=exp⁡(-λ|x|)$

Using the identity: $y ̃(k)=∫_{-∞}^{∞}\exp⁡(ikx)y(x)\,dx$

$y ̃(k)=∫_{-∞}^{∞}\exp⁡(ikx) exp⁡(-λ|x|)\,dx$

$y ̃(k)=∫_{0}^{∞}\exp⁡(ix(k-λ))+∫_{-\infty}^{0}\exp⁡(ix(k+λ))$

I do not know how to continue this as when i try to do it i can't define $exp(\infty)$, is there a identity that i can use

Comment: Your last rewrite is wrong, you dont have i in front of the $\lambda$

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=e^{-a|x|}$, then $$\sqrt{2\pi} F(k)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a|x|} e^{-ikx} dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{ax} e^{-ikx} dx+ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax} e^{-ikx}$$
$$\implies \sqrt{2\pi} F(k)=\frac{1}{a-ik}-\frac{1}{-a-ik}=\frac{2a}{a^2+k^2}$$